# Can you get a set of consecutive bits set in Java Bitset?

Tags: java, bitset

I have a `BitSet` and the info in it looks like this:

```
00011110111110
```

Is there any efficient method to get for example max number of continuous bits set? In the example above it would be `5`. Or is a  loop over the bit set efficient? I am just wondering if there is a another faster way

Comment: You could precompute all possible combinations of set bits, but that would be *less* efficient than simply looping through the bits and counting the highest number.

Comment: Is a loop not efficient enough?

Comment: If the maximum number of bits is fixed and small (around 12 or less) then you can calculate the number of continuous bits and use an array as a lookup table.  the index of the array would be the bits, interpreted as a number (long) and the value in the array element would be the number of continuous bits.

Comment: @SteveP. thats what I am wondering about!

Comment: @DwB the number of bits is arbitrary and it can be large.

Comment: So the lookup table will have 2^12 entries, right?

Comment: You can optimize the lookup table to ((2^12) - 1) by removing 0.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For sets of n bits there is a nice algorithm but it requires a shift of bits. Maybe doable with `BitSet.toLongArray` and `valueOf(long[])`. In incomplete code:

```
int maxNumberOfConsecutiveBits(BitSet bitSet) {
    int maxLength = 0;
    BitSet bs = bitSet.clone();
    while (!bs.isEmpty()) {
        ++maxLength;
        BitSet bs2 = shiftOne(bs);
        bs.and(bs2);
    }
    return maxLength;
}
```

The while loop will iterate upto maxLength.

Using `nextClearBit` iterates through all bits 0 and might be faster.

```
int maxNumberOfConsecutiveBits(BitSet bs) {
    int maxLength = 0;
    int onesI = bs.length(); // Points to the prior 0.
    for (int i = onesI; (i = bs.previousClearBit(i - 1)) >= 0; ) {
        int length = onesI - 1 - i;
        maxLength = Math.max(maxLength, length);
        i = bs.previousSetBit(i - 1) + 1; // Heuristic, optional.
        onesI = i;
    }
    return maxLength;
}
```

Personally I would need to time both solutions - for surprises.

Answer (score 0):

Proposed Algorithm:
Suppose we are in the middle of a `BitSet`, as of yet our longest run is 5.  We encounter our next `1`.  We can then skip four slots ahead.

- If the skipped to slot has a `1`, we continue until we get a 0. Then, we backtrack from our original skip spot and see if the run continues.  If the run is less than max, do nothing. If not, we set max run to the length of the run. Then, in either case, we change our next position to after the 0.
- If the skipped to slot has a `0`, we know that any run before this cannot be the max run.
- Repeat the above steps.

This is of course best case sublinear and worst case equivalent to looping the the list exactly once, as we are never checking a slot more than once.

Comment: I think this would actually be slower due to the speedups gains by branch prediction http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Branch_predication

Comment: @Jason Interesting. I can see that being true, but it wouldn't surprise me either way.  If that's the case, then I don't see a way of doing it faster than looping through the `BitSet`.  In general, algorithmically speaking, I think that this is a good solution.

Comment: @SteveP. if we skip 4 slots and there was 0 in one of them while the the slot 4 is 1, then it is gonna give the wrong answer because we assume all previous slots were 1. Did I miss anything?

Comment: @user3111560 Yes, you need to backtrack once you get a 0 to see what the values before the skip were: "Then, we backtrack from our original skip spot and see if the run continues."